# SQL Server : create function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, stored-functions

I am having a little trouble trying to create a function that I can call to generate a 32 character random ID.  I have it working in query editor but it is my understanding that to generate this in multiple lines of results accompanied by existing data from tables I have to create a function and call it.  Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Func_Gen_OID] (@NewOID varchar(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Length int = 32
DECLARE @Output varchar(32)
DECLARE @counter smallint
DECLARE @RandomNumber float
DECLARE @RandomNumberInt tinyint
DECLARE @CurrentCharacter varchar(1)
DECLARE @ValidCharacters varchar(255)
SET @ValidCharacters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
DECLARE @ValidCharactersLength int
SET @ValidCharactersLength = len(@ValidCharacters)
SET @CurrentCharacter = ''
SET @RandomNumber = 0
SET @RandomNumberInt = 0
SET @Output = ''

SET NOCOUNT ON

SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter < (@Length + 1)

BEGIN

        SET @RandomNumber = Rand()
        SET @RandomNumberInt = Convert(tinyint, ((@ValidCharactersLength - 1) * @RandomNumber + 1))

        SELECT @CurrentCharacter = SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, @RandomNumberInt, 1)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1

        SET @Output = @Output + @CurrentCharacter

RETURN @Output
END
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Just asking but why not just use a unique identifier with a default of newid(). It's not alpha numerical but gauranteed to be unique and is very random.

Answer (score 4):

instead of RAND() function, use this:

```
create view ViewRandomNumbers 
as 
   select rand( ) as Number 
go
```

Comment: Accurate, but there is an older answer explaining why this is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess you're seeing this error:

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.
```

You can't use RAND() inside a user-defined function directly (you'd need a view as an intermediary). And in this case, RAND would return the same value for every row of your query anyway as you haven't specified a varying seed (different for each call to the function).
If you want to encapsulate the rest of the logic inside the function, you will need to pass it a randomly-generated value from elsewhere, possibly generated via CHECKSUM() and NEWID().

There are some possibilities mentioned in this [SQL Server Central thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic666309-338-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys I was going about this the entire wrong way. I combined the use of a view with the NEWID() to get done what I needed creating the new view as: SELECT     REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(36), NEWID()), '-', '') AS OID

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I see:

1. You are returning @Output inside your while loop.
2. You don't need the input parameter as you aren't using it inside the function